# Trigger alert the third time, not the first

Tags: javascript

In the following I am getting alert for the first time. I need to trigger for the third time

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem("runOnce")) {
    alert("Page is loaded");
    sessionStorage.setItem("runOnce", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() { 
  let num = sessionStorage.getItem("runOnce"))
  num = num ? +num : 0; // num from storage will never be 0 so always truthy if set
  num++;
  if (num===3) alert("Page is loaded");
  sessionStorage.setItem("runOnce", num);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your session storage not clear after you restart your browser or reopen the window browser.

you can try `sessionStorage.clear()` to fix this thing.

Hope that can help you.